# Dilemma with tensors

Tags: metric-spaces, field-theory, tensors

I was reading lots of books lately on field theory, and unfortunately, a particular step in a calculation is causing me trouble. I cannot find the details of it in any book, and I couldn't derive it. It literally eluded me.
If we have a 4-vector

$j^\mu=-\omega^\rho_\nu T^\mu_\rho x^\nu$

where $\omega^\rho_\nu$ is an anti-symmetric tensor, and we have the conservation law

$\partial _\mu j^\mu=0$

then, (and this is the step I want to know how it happened), we can construct 6 conserved currents as follows:

$(J^\mu)^{\rho\sigma}=x^\rho T^{\mu\sigma}-x^\sigma T^{\mu\rho}$

where $T^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\nu\sigma} T^\mu_\sigma$

and $\eta^{\nu\sigma}$ are the contravariant components of the metric tensor of Minkowski spacetime, and we used Einstein summation convention, where a repeated index, once as a superscript and once as a subscript is summed over.

I would very much appreciate your help, because no one answered me on physics stack exchange.

Comment: Since they've told you what  the currents are, you only need to  check that they're conserved, i.e., $\partial_\mu(J^\mu)^{\rho\sigma}=0$. What happens if you just plug  the given formula for $J$ into the left side of that equation and see how much of it cancels? You'll probably need to use antisymmetry of $\omega$ and symmetry of $\eta$ and/or $T$.

Comment: Yeah, it works that way, but without the need to use the properties of $\omega^\mu_\nu$ .
But what I am interested in is how did they use the anti-symmetry of $\omega^\mu_\nu$ to get this relationship.